# In MouseMove event, how to determine if cursor is w/i certain distance of an edge?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

When the user moves the mouse over an object, I'm trying to do some hit-testing in my MouseMove event handler to detect when the cursor is w/i a certain distance from an edge of the object.  I suspect that in the MouseEnter handler I need to store the location of the object, then in MouseMove compare

```
e.GetPosition(this)
```

to the location +/- dimensions.
How do I get the position of an object relative to the same root that e.GetPosition(this) returns its Point?  e.GetPosition(this) returns a point relative to this; how can I determine if point.x is 1 pixel or 12 pixels from an edge of the containing object.
The goal is know if the mouse is w/i a certain distance of an object's edge.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you trying to detect if you clicked over a object? I'm confused about the MouseMove part.

Comment: When MouseEnter fires, I know the cursor is over the object.  As the user moves the mouse around, I want to know if the cursor is w/i a certain distance of an edge of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The MouseEventArgs GetPosition() function returns the position relative to the framework element that's passed to it (that is, the FrameworkElement in question can be `this`, but doesn't have to be).  So you could write something like:

```
bool isNearTarget=false;
FrameworkElement targetObject;
double nearDistance;

Point location=e.GetPosition(targetObject);
if((location.X>(-nearDistance)) && (location.X<nearDistance) ||
   (location.Y>(-nearDistance)) && (location.Y<nearDistance) ||
   (location.X>(targetObject.Width - nearDistance)) && 
       (location.X<targetObject.Width + nearDistance)) ||
   (location.Y>(targetObject.Height - nearDistance)) && 
       (location.Y<targetObject.Height + nearDistance)))
 {   
    isNearTarget=true;
 {
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making it too complicated...

```
MouseEnter()
{
        double txtBoxLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(sidesStackPanel);
        double txtBoxRight = txtBoxLeft + sidesStackPanel.ActualWidth;

        Point p = e.GetPosition(null);
        _leftGully = txtBoxLeft + _gullyWidth;
        _rightGully = txtBoxRight - _gullyWidth;
}
MouseMove()
{
    StackPanel sp = sender as StackPanel;

    if (null != sp)
    {
        Point p = e.GetPosition(sp);
        if (p.X <= _leftGully)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  Move: In left gully");
        }
        else if (p.X >= _rightGully)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  Move: In right gully");
        }
    }
}
```